# URL rewrite - REMOTE_USER always empty

Tags: iis, iis-7

I need to create a URL rewrite rule that adds the REMOTE_USER value to the query string.  I simplified my app down to absolute essentials.  However, the REMOTE_USER is always empty while the rule condition is evaluated.

My web site configured in IIS 7, app pool uses integrated mode with .NET 2.0.  I disabled Anonymous Auth and enabled Windows Auth on the site through IIS Manager and I even added the line to web.config to prevent anonymous access.  Here are my two files.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer> 
        <security> 
            <authorization> 
                <remove users="?" roles="" verbs="" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Add login into URL" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="login" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REMOTE_USER}" pattern="(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{HTTP_URL}?login={C:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

default.asp

```
<%= Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_USER") %>
```

My rule never hits because {REMOTE_USER} is always blank when conditions are evaluated (other server variables show up in the rule, so it's just {REMOTE_USER}).  The twist is that default.asp shows my REMOTE_USER value.

Any suggestions why this happened?   Thank you

Comment: Try change REMOTE_USER to AUTH_USER, or change Windows auth to Basic auth.

Comment: If I recall now, the answer that I found was that the rules were evaluated before user was authenticated and so this was impossible.  I ended up writing a proxy that redirected users to the appropriate site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I didn't find this link before.  As I suspected, auth runs after URL rewrite rules and REMOTE_USER can't be used to redirect.  I suppose I would have to write my own redirection module.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1155169.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

So, did you solve this?

Apparently, [ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) have been depreciated for C# in some instances.

If that is your case, you'll need to do it this way:

```
string login = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

If you really want to use ServerVariables, keep in mind they are **CaSe Sensitive** in C#. The correct casing is almost always *UPPER*, and here is the list of them:

[List of ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx)